# How to fix the execution of multiple Protocol Handler Calls?

Tags: google-chrome, protocol-handler

I work on an Angular application right now which tries to call multiple URL Protocol Handler Calls in short succession.
(For testing purposes we have 10 Calls with 0.5s delay between each other which are configured to open notepad.exe inside my registry)

This works completely fine in firefox and all 10 of the requested notepad instances get opened on my local machine, however when used with google chrome, only one instance gets opened and the remaining 9 calls are not handled at all.

Anyone knows a solution for this problem? Is it by design and if yes, is there a way to deactivate it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the only clue I have is that by installing the adblock plugin, the inconsistency is corrected with multiple calls at the same time.

Comment: This is implemented in chrome on purpose and there is no way around that.

Answered here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/g8bCddXd8F4